# Google Classroom API patch

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

When executing the `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch` method in the Google Classroom API, a 403 error is returned when I try to update the student's submission. Below is my code.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client
import simplejson as json

class Google:
    SCOPE = {
        "profile": {"scope": "profile email", "access_type": "offline"},
        "classroom": {"scope": 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly '
                               'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly '
                                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails '
                                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos ',
                    "access_type": "offline"},
        "classwork":{
            "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me",
            "access_type":"offline"
        },
        "submission":{
            "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students profile email",
            "access_type":"offline"
        }
    }
    ERRORS = {
                "invalid_request":{"code":"invalid_request","msg":"Invalid request. Please Try with login again."},
                "account_used":{"code":"account_used","msg":"Google account is already configured with different PracTutor Account."},
                "assignment_permission_denied":{"code":"assignment_permission_denied","msg":"permission denied"},
                "unknown_error":{"code":"unknown_error","msg":"something went wrong."}
              }

    def __init__(self, code = "", genFor = "profile"):
        if code:
            genFor = genFor if genFor else "profile"
            self.credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(pConfig['googleOauthSecretFile'],self.SCOPE[genFor]["scope"], code)
            self.http_auth = self.credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
            cred_json = self.credentials.to_json()
            idinfo = json.loads(cred_json)["id_token"]
        else:
            raise ValueError(Google.ERRORS["invalid_request"])

    def getUserInfo(self):
        service = build(serviceName='oauth2', version='v2', http=self.http_auth)
        idinfo = service.userinfo().get().execute()
        return idinfo

    def getClasses(self):
        courses = []
        page_token = None
        service = build('classroom', 'v1', http=self.http_auth)
        while True:
            response = service.courses().list(teacherId="me",pageToken=page_token,
                                              pageSize=100).execute()
            courses.extend(response.get('courses', []))
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if not page_token:
                break
        return courses

    def getStudent(self,course_id):
        students = []
        page_token = None
        service = build('classroom', 'v1', http=self.http_auth)
        while True:
            response = service.courses().students().list(courseId=course_id, pageToken=page_token,
                                              pageSize=100).execute()
            students.extend(response.get('students', []))
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if not page_token:
                break
        return students

    def createAssignment(self,course_id,**kwargs):
        service = build('classroom', 'v1', http=self.http_auth)
        date, time = kwargs["dueDate"].split(" ")
        yy,mm,dd = date.split("-")
        h,m,s = time.split(":")
        courseWork = {
            'title': kwargs["title"],
            'description': kwargs["desc"],
            'materials': [
                {'link': { 'url': kwargs["link"] } },
            ],
            'dueDate': {
                "month": mm,
                "year": yy,
                "day": dd
            },
            'dueTime':{
                "hours": h,
                "minutes": m,
                "seconds": s
              },
            'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',
            'state': 'PUBLISHED',
        }
        courseWork = service.courses().courseWork().create(courseId=course_id, body=courseWork).execute()
        return courseWork

    def submitAssignment(self,**kwargs):
        service = build('classroom', 'v1', http=self.http_auth)
        course_id = kwargs["courseId"]
        courseWorkId = kwargs["courseWorkId"]
        score = kwargs["score"]
        studentSubmission = {
            'assignedGrade': score,
            'draftGrade': score,
            'assignmentSubmission': {
                'attachments': [
                    {
                        'link': {
                            "url": "demo.com",
                            "title": "Assignment1",
                            "thumbnailUrl": "demo.com",
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
            'state': 'TURNED_IN',
        }
        gCredentials = json.loads(self.credentials.to_json())
        userGId = gCredentials["id_token"]["sub"]
        studentSubmissionsData = service.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(
            courseId=course_id,
            courseWorkId=courseWorkId,
            userId=userGId).execute()
        studentSubmissionId = studentSubmissionsData["studentSubmissions"][0]["id"]
        courseWorkRes = service.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().patch(
                    courseId=course_id,
                    courseWorkId=courseWorkId,
                    id=studentSubmissionId,
                    updateMask='assignedGrade,draftGrade',
                    body=studentSubmission).execute()
        return courseWorkRes


Method Calling     
g = Google()
kwargs = {"courseId":courseId,"courseWorkId":courseWorkId,"score":80}
courseworkResponse = g.submitAssignment(**kwargs)
```

Error:

> https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courses_id}/courseWork/{courseWork_id}/studentSubmissions/{studentSubmissions_id}?alt=json&updateMask=assignedGrade%2CdraftGrade
>   returned "The caller does not have permission">

Student's submission contains following fields assignedGrade, draftGrade, attachments (Link resource) and state.

The call is being made from an authenticated student account. The Developer Console project has the Google Classroom API enabled, and other calls to the Google Classroom API are working fine, such as courses.courseWork.create and courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list. Also I am making request from the same Developer Console project from course work item is associated/created.

The same error 403 error with different message is returned when I am trying from Google API explorer.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: What scope did you authenticate said student with?

Answer (score 0):

That error message basically means that you don't have permission to do what it is you are trying to do.   The permissions are related to what scopes you have authenticated the user with.    here is a full list of [scopes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth#OAuth2Authorizing)

[Method: courses.courseWork.studentSubmis.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch)  requires the following scopes.

**Authorization**

Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me
```

**Use List and Get before patch**

Use list and get before patch to be sure that you have the corect ids.

If you have the user preform a [list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) first then find the one you are after then preform a [get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/get)  you can make changes to the object in the get then run your update on that.  Doing it this way ensures that all the ids you are passing are correct and that the user does in fact have access to what they are trying to update.

Comment: Yes,  I am using both scope to authenticate.

Comment: When it pops up and request authentication of the user.  Is it asking for the coursework scopes?    I don't have the power of python but normally you send scopes as an an array not split up like that.

Comment: Yes, it is asking for the coursework scope. 
`Manage your course work and view your grades in Google Classroom. Manage course work and grades for students in the Google Classroom classes you teach and view the course work and grades for classes you administer.`